# Не получается корректно расположить контейнеры на bootstrap

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, bootstrap

Делаю userpage для своего сайта с элементами Boostrap. Не могу корректно расположить объект. Пробовал и padding, и margin, и позицию ставил на absolute. Нужна помощь.

для лучшего понимания прикреплю скриншот ожидание/реальность:
[image: Ожидание]
[image: Реальность]

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta property="og:image" content="https://ai-covers.ru/fav.jpg"/>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/sitedeniska/css/users.css">
        <title>Ai Covers - Моя страница</title>

        <!-- Meta tags opened -->
        <meta name="title" content="Ai Covers">
        <meta name="description" content="Создатель AI каверов живет тут">
        <meta name="keywords" content="how to make an ai cover tutorial,tutorial how to make an ai cover,ai cover tutorial,tutorial,how to make ai cover,how to make an ai cover,how to make a cover with ai,cover,ai cover,make ai cover,how to ai cover,michael jackson,how to make kanye sing,how to make a song with ai,ai,so vits svc,artificial intelligence,kanye west,нейросеть,artificial,intelligence,so-vits-svc,the weeknd,song,fixing so vits svc,ai voice,sovitssvc,модель голоса, ai covers, аи каверы, kalomaze, rvc, rvc2">
        <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <meta name="language" content="Russian">
        <meta name="author" content="HeckerAI">
        <!-- Meta tags closed -->

        <!-- Yandex.Metrika counter -->
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            (function(m,e,t,r,i,k,a){m[i]=m[i]||function(){(m[i].a=m[i].a||[]).push(arguments)};
            m[i].l=1*new Date();
            for (var j = 0; j < document.scripts.length; j++) {if (document.scripts[j].src === r) { return; }}
            k=e.createElement(t),a=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],k.async=1,k.src=r,a.parentNode.insertBefore(k,a)})
            (window, document, "script", "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/tag.js", "ym");
        
            ym(94779721, "init", {
                clickmap:true,
                trackLinks:true,
                accurateTrackBounce:true
            });
        </script>
        <noscript><div><img src="https://mc.yandex.ru/watch/94779721" style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;" alt="" /></div></noscript>
        <!-- /Yandex.Metrika counter -->     
    </head>

    <body data-bs-theme="dark" style="background: radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #1b2735 0%, #090a0f 100%) no-repeat center center fixed; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover; -o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Tenth navbar example">
            <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarsExample08" aria-controls="navbarsExample08" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="navbar-collapse justify-content-md-center collapse" id="navbarsExample08">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="https://ai-covers.ru">Главная</a>
                        </li> 
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown" data-bs-theme="dark">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Информация</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ai-covers.ru/authors">Авторы</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://ai-covers.ru/ai">Нейросеть</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                          <a class="nav-link active" href="/covers">Каверы</a>
                        </li>
                        </ul>

                        <div class="dropdown" style="margin-left: 2px;">
                            <a href="#" class="d-block link-body-emphasis text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img src="/Загрузки/attachment.gif" alt="mdo" width="32" height="32" class="rounded-circle">
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu text-small">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Загрузить кавер...</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Настройки</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Профиль</a></li>
                                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../api/users/logout.php">Выйти</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div class="bg-animation" style="z-index: -2;">
            <div id="stars"></div>
            <div id="stars2"></div>
            <div id="stars3"></div>
            <div id="stars4"></div>
        </div>

        <div>

            

            <div class="container username">
                <div class="row row-cols-2 align-items-start start-0">
                    <div class="col-auto">
                        <img src="/Загрузки/attachment.gif" alt="avatar" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; border-radius: 25px">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <h1 class="text-left text-nowrap display-5 text-body-emphasis h-1 mb-3 onest static w-auto">User</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         
    
            <div class="modal modal-sheet position-relative d-block bg-transparent p-4 py-md-5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalTour">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content rounded-4" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
                    <div class="modal-body p-5">
                      <h2 class="fw-bold mb-0">What's new</h2>
              
                      <ul class="d-grid gap-4 my-5 list-unstyled small">
                        <li class="d-flex gap-4">
                          <svg class="bi text-body-secondary flex-shrink-0" width="48" height="48"><use xlink:href="#grid-fill"/></svg>
                          <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Astral step</h5>
                            Not into lists? Try the new grid view.
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex gap-4">
                          <svg class="bi text-warning flex-shrink-0" width="48" height="48"><use xlink:href="#bookmark-star"/></svg>
                          <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Bookmarks</h5>
                            Save items you love for easy access later.
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex gap-4">
                          <svg class="bi text-primary flex-shrink-0" width="48" height="48"><use xlink:href="#film"/></svg>
                          <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Video embeds</h5>
                            Share videos wherever you go.
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mt-5 w-100" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Great, thanks!</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal modal-sheet position-relative d-block bg-transparent p-4 py-md-5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalTour">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content rounded-4" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
                    <div class="modal-body p-5">
                      <h2 class="fw-bold mb-0">What's new</h2>
              
                      <ul class="d-grid gap-4 my-5 list-unstyled small">
                        <li class="d-flex gap-4">
                          <svg class="bi text-body-secondary flex-shrink-0" width="48" height="48"><use xlink:href="#grid-fill"/></svg>
                          <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Astral step</h5>
                            Not into lists? Try the new grid view.
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex gap-4">
                          <svg class="bi text-warning flex-shrink-0" width="48" height="48"><use xlink:href="#bookmark-star"/></svg>
                          <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Bookmarks</h5>
                            Save items you love for easy access later.
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex gap-4">
                          <svg class="bi text-primary flex-shrink-0" width="48" height="48"><use xlink:href="#film"/></svg>
                          <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Video embeds</h5>
                            Share videos wherever you go.
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mt-5 w-100" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Great, thanks!</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal modal-sheet position-static d-block bg-transparent p-4 py-md-5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="modalTour">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                  <div class="modal-content rounded-4" style="background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);">
                    <div class="modal-body p-5">
                      <h2 class="fw-bold mb-0">What's new</h2>
              
                      <ul class="d-grid gap-4 my-5 list-unstyled small">
                        <li class="d-flex gap-4">
                          <svg class="bi text-body-secondary flex-shrink-0" width="48" height="48"><use xlink:href="#grid-fill"/></svg>
                          <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Astral step</h5>
                            Not into lists? Try the new grid view.
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex gap-4">
                          <svg class="bi text-warning flex-shrink-0" width="48" height="48"><use xlink:href="#bookmark-star"/></svg>
                          <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Bookmarks</h5>
                            Save items you love for easy access later.
                          </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="d-flex gap-4">
                          <svg class="bi text-primary flex-shrink-0" width="48" height="48"><use xlink:href="#film"/></svg>
                          <div>
                            <h5 class="mb-0">Video embeds</h5>
                            Share videos wherever you go.
                          </div>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mt-5 w-100" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Great, thanks!</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
              <footer class="d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center py-3 my-4 border-top">
                <div class="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center">
                  <a href="/" class="mb-3 me-2 mb-md-0 text-body-secondary text-decoration-none lh-1">
                    <svg class="bi" width="30" height="24"><use xlink:href="#"></use></svg>
                  </a>
                  <span class="mb-3 mb-md-0 text-body-secondary">© HeckerAI, 2023</span>
                </div>

                <ul class="nav col-md-4 justify-content-end list-unstyled d-flex">
                    <li class="ms-3"><a class="text-body-secondary" href="mailto:support@ai-covers.ru"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-envelope-at-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path d="M2 2A2 2 0 0 0 .05 3.555L8 8.414l7.95-4.859A2 2 0 0 0 14 2H2Zm-2 9.8V4.698l5.803 3.546L0 11.801Zm6.761-2.97-6.57 4.026A2 2 0 0 0 2 14h6.256A4.493 4.493 0 0 1 8 12.5a4.49 4.49 0 0 1 1.606-3.446l-.367-.225L8 9.586l-1.239-.757ZM16 9.671V4.697l-5.803 3.546.338.208A4.482 4.482 0 0 1 12.5 8c1.414 0 2.675.652 3.5 1.671Z"/> <path d="M15.834 12.244c0 1.168-.577 2.025-1.587 2.025-.503 0-1.002-.228-1.12-.648h-.043c-.118.416-.543.643-1.015.643-.77 0-1.259-.542-1.259-1.434v-.529c0-.844.481-1.4 1.26-1.4.585 0 .87.333.953.63h.03v-.568h.905v2.19c0 .272.18.42.411.42.315 0 .639-.415.639-1.39v-.118c0-1.277-.95-2.326-2.484-2.326h-.04c-1.582 0-2.64 1.067-2.64 2.724v.157c0 1.867 1.237 2.654 2.57 2.654h.045c.507 0 .935-.07 1.18-.18v.731c-.219.1-.643.175-1.237.175h-.044C10.438 16 9 14.82 9 12.646v-.214C9 10.36 10.421 9 12.485 9h.035c2.12 0 3.314 1.43 3.314 3.034v.21Zm-4.04.21v.227c0 .586.227.8.581.8.31 0 .564-.17.564-.743v-.367c0-.516-.275-.708-.572-.708-.346 0-.573.245-.573.791Z"/>
                      <use xlink:href="#mail"></use></svg></a></li>
                      <li class="ms-3"><a class="text-body-secondary" href="/telegram"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-telegram" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path d="M16 8A8 8 0 1 1 0 8a8 8 0 0 1 16 0zM8.287 5.906c-.778.324-2.334.994-4.666 2.01-.378.15-.577.298-.595.442-.03.243.275.339.69.47l.175.055c.408.133.958.288 1.243.294.26.006.549-.1.868-.32 2.179-1.471 3.304-2.214 3.374-2.23.05-.012.12-.026.166.016.047.041.042.12.037.141-.03.129-1.227 1.241-1.846 1.817-.193.18-.33.307-.358.336a8.154 8.154 0 0 1-.188.186c-.38.366-.664.64.015 1.088.327.216.589.393.85.571.284.194.568.387.936.629.093.06.183.125.27.187.331.236.63.448.997.414.214-.02.435-.22.547-.82.265-1.417.786-4.486.906-5.751a1.426 1.426 0 0 0-.013-.315.337.337 0 0 0-.114-.217.526.526 0 0 0-.31-.093c-.3.005-.763.166-2.984 1.09z"/><use xlink:href="#telegram"></use></svg></a></li>
                    <li class="ms-3"><a class="text-body-secondary" href="/youtube"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-youtube" viewBox="0 0 16 16"> <path d="M8.051 1.999h.089c.822.003 4.987.033 6.11.335a2.01 2.01 0 0 1 1.415 1.42c.101.38.172.883.22 1.402l.01.104.022.26.008.104c.065.914.073 1.77.074 1.957v.075c-.001.194-.01 1.108-.082 2.06l-.008.105-.009.104c-.05.572-.124 1.14-.235 1.558a2.007 2.007 0 0 1-1.415 1.42c-1.16.312-5.569.334-6.18.335h-.142c-.309 0-1.587-.006-2.927-.052l-.17-.006-.087-.004-.171-.007-.171-.007c-1.11-.049-2.167-.128-2.654-.26a2.007 2.007 0 0 1-1.415-1.419c-.111-.417-.185-.986-.235-1.558L.09 9.82l-.008-.104A31.4 31.4 0 0 1 0 7.68v-.123c.002-.215.01-.958.064-1.778l.007-.103.003-.052.008-.104.022-.26.01-.104c.048-.519.119-1.023.22-1.402a2.007 2.007 0 0 1 1.415-1.42c.487-.13 1.544-.21 2.654-.26l.17-.007.172-.006.086-.003.171-.007A99.788 99.788 0 0 1 7.858 2h.193zM6.4 5.209v4.818l4.157-2.408L6.4 5.209z"/>
                    <use xlink:href="#youtube"></use></svg></a></li>
                </ul>
              </footer>
            </div>
        </div>

        

        
        
        
    

        



        <script src="/js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Onest';
     src: local("Onest"),
     url("/sitedeniska/onest/Onest-Black.woff2") format("woff2"),
     url("/sitedeniska/onest/Onest-Black.woff") format("woff");
    font-weight: 900; 
    font-style: normal;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container{
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
}

.onest{
    font-family: "Onest", "Arial", sans-serif; font-weight:bold;
}

.static{
    position: static;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.text-truncate {
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap
}

.username {
    padding-top: 50px;
}

.star {
  background-color: #878787;
  width: 2px;
  height: 2px;
  z-index: -2;
  
}

@keyframes fadeInUpLayout {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateY(1.19vw)
    }
}

.layout__animate {
    transform: translateY(0);
    will-change: auto
}

.layout__animate.layout__animation-1 {
    animation: fadeInUpLayout .75s 0s backwards
}

.layout__animate.layout__animation-2 {
    animation: fadeInUpLayout .75s .05s backwards
}

.layout__animate.layout__animation-3 {
    animation: fadeInUpLayout .75s .1s backwards
}

.layout__animate.layout__animation-4 {
    animation: fadeInUpLayout .75s .15s backwards
}

.layout__animate.layout__animation-5 {
    animation: fadeInUpLayout .75s .2s backwards
}
```

Comment: хотите в ряд эти блоки с текстами? средствами bootstrap не пробовали воспользоваться? родительскому контейнеру класс row, а каждую модалку в свой контейнера с классом col-4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то разметка у вас не правильная, минимальный пример:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container ">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-primary">тут ваша What's new</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
       <div class="bg-primary">тут ваша What's new</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="bg-primary">тут ваша What's new</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

И почитайте этот [раздел](https://bootstrap-4.ru/docs/5.3/layout/grid/)